# How can I deploy my Laravel 4 site onto Windows Azure?

Tags: php, azure, deployment, laravel, laravel-4

I have tried many things, but I am either getting the error "You have no permission" or just a blank page.  I tried renaming the public folder into wwwroot, and creating a web.config file.

I followed the tutorial here: http://bigbitecreative.com/deploying-laravel-4-azure/ as well as a few others but that didnt seem to work for me.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using Azure Website or Azure VM?

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a VM with ubuntu.
2. Install LAMP ([link](http://goo.gl/bhjW7s))
3. Create a virtual host and point your document root to the public folder of laravel. ([link](http://goo.gl/Ci9q9b))

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a proper answer but maybe it will help you out.  I've been looking into this myself on and off for a while.  You can easily change what Azure considers the root directory. Go to the `configure` page for your Azure website and scroll all the way to the bottom.  You should find the `virtual applications and directories` section. By default you should see one entry for `/` pointing to `site\wwwroot`.  Just add `\public` to this path and you will be directed to the `public` folder of your laravel install.

The problem that I'm having is how to make command line calls to `composer` and `artisan`.  I was able to get the "You have arrived" page by uploading my vendor folder from my local machine but obviously this isn't ideal.